# Conversion between Graph API MailFolder ID and PowerShell FolderID formats?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Using the [List mailFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0) or [List childFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-childfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0) APIs from Graph, I get back a `MailFolder` object that has an `id` property that represents the folder's unique ID. Here's an example:

```
"id": "AAMkAGUxZmVhZmQ5LWZmYzgtNDFiYy05NTgxLTcxOTA3OTY2ZTUyZAAuAAAAAADWewXmOP3rTYK4i34W6nCTAQDJBUrfh_-1Try-wjHqXpxrAAAAAAFZAAA=",
"displayName": "Archive"
```

When using PowerShell to get the same folder using `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`, the `id` is returned in a different format.

```
FolderPath: /Archive                                         
FolderId: LgAAAADWewXmOP3rTYK4i34W6nCTAQDJBUrfh+/1Try/wjHqXpxrAAAAAAFZAAAB
```

Is there a way to convert between these different representations of the same ID?

The problem I have is that I get the folder information (including ID) using Graph, but then I need to do something with that information that isn't currently supported by Graph (like getting folder permissions).

What I'd like to do is use the command below, but it only accepts the format returned by `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics`:

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user@contoso.com:$($id)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Folder ID from EWS to Exchange Cmdlet's Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383857/converting-folder-id-from-ews-to-exchange-cmdlets-identity)

Comment: That does look like it could be the same issue, though I was not aware of a connection between Graph and EWS. As I've never used EWS, I'm not immediately sure how to do the translation in either my (Node) app or in PowerShell, but I appreciate the pointer. Thanks!